# How to run all the tests specified in files with a naming convention like *_unit_test.go in a Golang project?

Tags: go, testing, circleci

I run go tests for a large project on ci. It takes around 30mins to complete. For some branches, I just need to run tests in *_unit_test.go file.

go test -run takes a regexp of the test name not file names.
if we pass individual files(1_unit_test.go) need to pass the dependant go files along with it.
if we use build tags, need to add them to all the tests to have control over what can be run.

Answer (score 2):

> How to run all the tests specified in files with a naming convention like *_unit_test.go in a Go[...] project?

You cannot.

As you already discovered you either have to use naming conventions on the actual *Tests*, use build tags or skip tests pragmatically via t.Skip based on some condition (like flags or environment variables).